# :? Conditional Operator Unexpected Evaluation Behavior

Tags: c#, .net

Can someone explain why the following throws an ArgumentNullException:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
            IEnumerable<int> lst= null;
            var msg = ",lst=" + lst!= null ? String.Join(",", lst) : "null";
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
        }
```

and this doesn't:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
            IEnumerable<int> lst= null;
            var msg = ",lst=" + (lst!= null ? String.Join(",", lst) : "null");
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
        }
```

Comment: What do you expect `",lst=" + lst` to do when `lst` is null?

Comment: Because `+` is a [higher precedence operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx) than `!=`.

Comment: Basically this is an order of operations issue.  Without the parens it's going to do `",lst" + lst` before the `null` comparison.

Comment: Makes sense! please post these as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: `(",lst=" + lst )!= null` is the evaluate expression to true so `String.Join(",", lst)` throw `ArgumentNullException`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the [operator precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx) Your first line of code

```
var msg = ",lst=" + lst!= null ? String.Join(",", lst) : "null";
```

is equivalent to

```
var msg = (",lst=" + lst) != null ? String.Join(",", lst) : "null";
```

And since `lst` is `null` it throws Argument Null Exception in `String.Join`

May be a good time to invest in Resharper, look at the warning....

[image]